# load xml file after reading in string

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml

I have read an xml file as a string due to cryptography.

```
string xmlString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("../../liberal.xml");
//how to load xml document here?
XmlDocument xmlDo = new XmlDocument();
xmlDo.Load("../../liberal.xml");
```

The above code throws error and doesn't load.

XML file doesn't have any root elements and right now liberal XML file looks like this `dasjkhf8dfkbhdflak3kjbdf+fafas(safasasdfjgdskalfguv.ng;FHSDAFKLASDF`.

Couldn't load xml document with this data format. Only if I can load XML document I will be able to use their properties to add new values to the xml file.

**Update1:**

I decrypted the xml and placed in a string, but couldn't load the xml document with that string.

```
string retValue;
XmlDocument dec = new XmlDocument();
dec.Load(retValue);
```

retValue string has values like this.

```
<Product><Type>Metal</Type><Department>Foundry</Department></Product>
```

Error Message

```
Illegal characters in path.
```

Really appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Is that valid XML ? If it is not valid XML, why are you trying to load that to XmlDocument ?

Comment: @Shyju - It's an xml document which will have encrypted strings only.

Comment: But you said "XML file doesn't have any root elements and right now XML file has data like this "

Comment: So you would have to decrypt it first. How would you expect XmlDocument.Load to know how to decrypt your data?

Comment: @mikemind, it seems, it does not have xml tags, So have to dencrypt it first then load using XmlDocument

Comment: It'd be helpful to show your liberal.xml document to check if it's valid XML markup. Also, what exception (as well as message) does the application throw?

Comment: @Nathangrad - didn't you read the Q? he has an encrypted string as a doc. there is no xml to see.

Comment: @MdAyubAliSarker - I encrypted the xml and placed in string and couldn't load that to xmldocument.  Take a look at my updated post.

Comment: @Darren I assumed he had decrypted it before loading - need to check if the decryption process returns valid XML markup

Comment: @Nathangrad - I had decrypted and it returns a valid xml format. Updated my post. Please take a look.

Comment: @mikemind - now your question is TOTALLY different from what it was originally!

Comment: @mikemind Take a look at the links in my answer - they'll explain more about the purpose of each one along with some more examples. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `XmlDocument.Load(string)` method which accepts a **path** to an XML file. You need to use the `XmlDocument.LoadXml(string)` method which accepts any valid XML **markup**. 
Two completely different parameters. 
Example:

```
// XmlDocument.LoadXml(string)

string decryptedMarkup = "<Product><Type>Metal</Type>"
    + "<Department>Foundry</Department></Product>";
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(decryptedMarkup);


// XmlDocument.Load(string)

string pathToFile = "test.xml";
XmlDocument xmlDoc2 = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc2.Load(pathToFile);
```

For further information, take a look at:
[XmlDocument.Load(string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/875kz807(v=vs.110).aspx)

> String parameter:
> URL for the file containing the XML document to load. The URL can be either a local file or an HTTP URL (a Web address).

[XmlDocument.LoadXml(string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml(v=vs.110).aspx)

> String parameter:
> String containing the XML document to load.